# auto logoff from all apps on android

Tags: android, logout, logoff

i want a functionality where i can log off from all the apps on android ie: auto logoff from skype , facebook , yahoo.

Is a some app already available for this or some easy way to implement this. I tried clearing all the cache but does not log out the app.

their is a app called social secure for ios but nothing for android

Comment: you want to find an app / you want to write an app for this function ?

Comment: This question might be more relevant at http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ShivanRaptor If their a program then its better else a function would be good

Comment: @P.T. moving it to that section thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't acheive it programmatically because of Android SDK restrictions in PackageManager and because Skype,Facebook,Yahoo or other apps don't have a public API for it,but you can simply clean **application data** to logout.

If the device is **rooted** and you can execute **su** command in the shell,
Than it will be quite simple :
1. Get list of all installed application on the device by using [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)
2. Filter this list by checking theirs package names
3. Execute in the shell `su pm clear package.name`
(you can use [Stericson RootTools](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/))

That's it.